# Common Data Model with wso2bps and wso2greg

Tags: wso2

I am evaluating wso2 and came across the following issue: imagine that my company already has a well defined Common Data Model for their business. Those schemas (and even service definitions - wsdls) live on a repository and references between files are done using relative paths between them. Now, what I want is to import all of these XSD's and WSDL's into wso2 Gorvernance Registry (wso2greg) to make it manage them. More (and this is where I start to lose the grip on wso2) I want to reference wso2greg's resources on wso2bps's BPEL Workflows. I want to say: "Hey, workflow! Forget all about your auto-generated interface. Your interface will be this one {wsdl_from_wso2greg}."

I am trying to accomplish this by creating an Registry Resources Project inside my "main" Carbon Application Project (along-side with my BPEL Workflow) and then creating PartnerLinks on the workflow but, after I configured everything, I get the following error: "The import location of ../TestGreg/TestServiceWsdl.wsdl is not supported by this implementation. Import artifacts must be contained within the folder hierarchy that has the deployment descriptor at the root".

Now, am I doing something really stupid or wso2 really does not support what I am trying to do? If so, how do you guys usually deal with these issues?

Thks, 
Leandro Nunes

Answer (score 0):

When you are referring to WSDLs/XSDs from BPEL, you need to package them with BPEL. You cannot refer the ones stored in the registry.
Referring from the external registry can be done only for security policies and endpoint references. Any other resources need to be packaged with the BPEL.